# Multitouch Gestures with useGesture in React

Tags: reactjs, multi-touch, react-use-gesture

I'd like to detect multi-finger taps and swipes.
Eg. detect a two finger tap or a four finger swipe down as such.
Using regular React and `useGesture`.

I'd like to know if it's even possible, because there's no mention of this in the docs. And any guidance to where I could find what I'm looking for (perhaps [Ionic Gestures](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/gestures)?)

Answer (score 0):

For a multi-touch tap, you can detect a tap using (for example) the dragGesture.

When it comes to multi-touch swipe, I'm currently looking for that answer as well.

Set the option "filterTaps: true", and look at the "tap" and "touches" variables in the gesture state as defined here: https://use-gesture.netlify.app/docs/state/

```
const bind = useDrag(
({ tap, touches }) => {

  if (tap && touches > 1) {
    // Do stuff
  }

  ...

},
{
  filterTaps: true,
  useTouch: true,
})
```